# NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Migrator::Zlib

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm new to Ruby and Active Record. I'm trying to run my first migration with the command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I keep getting this error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Migrator::Zlib.

I've tried with different projects and all migrations are getting this error.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know whats up with this, took my entire day to find a solution

at the top of your environment.rb

```
require 'zlib'
```

this worked for me :)

Comment: I think that suggestion might work but what ended up working for me was running this in my home directory: $ gem install rubygems-bundler
$ gem regenerate_binstubs

Comment: Yah that seems like a more suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to `Rakefile`:

`require 'zlib'`